# Caching with Parse Service

Tags: java, android, caching, save

I'm having trouble trying to cache data from Parse.com.

I've been reading the [Parse API for caching](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-caching), but i'm still having trouble understanding it. How do I extract data and cache with this?

```
query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
  if (e == null) {
    // Results were successfully found, looking first on the
    // network and then on disk.
  } else {
    // The network was inaccessible and we have no cached data
    // for this query.
}
});
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? I'm having the same.

Answer (score 2):

The data is cached automatically on the internal storage if you specify a `CachePolicy`. The default one is the `CachePolicy.IGNORE_CACHE` so no data is cached. Since you are interested in getting the results from cache, it would make more sense to use the `CachePolicy.CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK` so the query will look first inside the cache. The data you are looking for is stored in your case in the variable `scoreList`.

Maybe it is difficult for you to understand how your code works because you're using the callback (because of `findinBackground()`). Consider the following code:

```
ParseQuery<Person> personParseQuery = new ParseQuery<Person>(Person.class);
personParseQuery.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
personParseQuery.addAscendingOrder("sort_order");
List<Person> = personParseQuery.find();
```

As you can see, the result of the query is return by the `find()` method. From the Parse API documentation: 
    `public List<T> find() throws ParseException` -
    **Retrieves a list of ParseObjects that satisfy this query. Uses the network and/or the cache, depending on the cache policy.**

The `Person` class may look like this:

```
@ParseClassName("Person")
public class Person extends ParseObject {

    public Person(){}

    public String getPersonName() {
        return getString("personName");
    }

    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        put("personName",personName);
    }
}
```

And of course, don't forget to initialize Parse first and register the `Person` class:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "appID", "clientID");
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Person.class);
```

I hope my explanation can help you.

PS: You can see the data is cached by looking inside the data.data. your application package+name .cache.com.parse folder on your emulator after executing the code.